# How to print next line on current line if next line contains some character?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

If the next line is `b`, I want to add it to the `AA` line.

This is my file:

```
AA  
b  
b  
AA  
b  
AA  
b  
b  
b
```

Desired output:

```
AA b b  
AA b  
AA b b b
```

The below is the code I am trying.

```
paste -s -d" " file.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i > 1 && $i == "AA")????}}'
```

I printed several line in one line and tried to run for loop to the last field and go down to the next line if `$i` is `AA`. But I do not know what to do after the 'if' statement.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

POSIXLY:

```
sed -ne '
  /^AA$/b1
  :1
    $!N
    /\nb$/s/\n/ /
    t1
  P;D
' <file
```